# Bizarre max {} notation

Tags: supply-and-demand

My professor gave us the following problem, but it uses a notation/syntax I haven't seen before $(q_{luke} = max \{ \dots \})$. She hasn't explained it or introduced it to us prior to this.

[image]

What does this mean? I assume it must be somehow translatable into $y=mx+b$ form given the context of the problem, but I'm not sure how. Thanks!

Comment: It means the maximum of $90-4p$ and $0$; that is, if $90-4p$ becomes negative (due to $p$ large), then $q_\text{lea}=0$ (for all $p$ such that $90-4p<0$).

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer. If you write this up as an answer instead of a comment Jay can accept it and you'll get points for your answer.

Comment: Except that it is more of an answer than a comment. :-P

Comment: So the professor is eliminating any negative values which are unplottable on the graph and theoretically shouldn't happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**max {a, b, c} means the highest of these elements.**

For example, if "b" is higher than a and c, then max {a, b, c} = b

Comment: Worth noting is that there is also a function, $\min \{\}$ where you take the lowest, or minimum, of the elements in the bracket.